# Python.el - Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil

Tags: python

When I try to do `C-c C-c` to run my buffer (python.el), I get the error: `Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil`. This is what the backtrace looks like:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument arrayp nil)                                                                                                                       
  replace-regexp-in-string("[^-0-9a-zA-Z_./\n]" "\\\\\\&" nil)                                                                                                                       
  shell-quote-argument(nil)                                                                                                                                                          
  python-shell-parse-command()                                                                                                                                                       
  byte-code("^H\203^S^@\301\302\303 \"\304\305!\306^H!\307UE\207\303 \310\311E\207" [current-prefix-arg read-string "Run Python: " python-shell-parse-command y-or-n-p "Make dedicat$
  call-interactively(run-python)                                                                                                                                                     
  python-shell-get-or-create-process()                                                                                                                                               
  python-shell-send-region(1 598 nil)                                                                                                                                                
  python-shell-send-buffer(nil)                                                                                                                                                      
  call-interactively(python-shell-send-buffer nil nil)                                                                                                                               
  command-execute(python-shell-send-buffer)
```

Anyone know what's going on? I'm fairly new to emacs, but `C-c C-c` has never worked for me because of this error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to lie with `python-shell-parse-command`. It is passing `nil` to `shell-quote-argument`, and that function expects a string argument, not `nil`. (Actually, it passes `nil` on to `replace-regexp-in-string`, who complains. But I'm betting that `shell-quote-argument` needs a string arg.

Consider reporting this as a bug to the maintainer of `python-shell-parse-command`, aka of `python-shell-send-buffer`.

BTW, you will get a more complete backtrace if you load the source file instead of the byte-compiled file, for the code that defines `run-python`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `python-shell-interpreter` variable is not set properly.

You can examine this variable with `C-h C-v python-shell-interpreter`. It should be a string containing the path to your Python interpreter. (On Linux & Mac OS you can check where your interpreter is with `which python` on your command line).

You can set it with `(setq python-shell-interpreter <path to your Python interpreter>)`. A quick, permanent fix would be to set it in your [init.el](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) file.